# How to configure Azure storage credentials in perfkit?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run "object_storage_service" benchmark of google perfkit against azure storage. I see that the documentation says to pass the credentials as part of a .boto file. But looks like this file can take aws credentials or gce credentials. How to pass in Azure credentials?

.\pkb.py --cloud=Azure --machine_type=ExtraSmall --benchmarks=object_storage_service*

Answer (score 0):

Once you've done this step https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/PerfKitBenchmarker#windows-azure-cli-and-credentials are you sure the object_storage_service benchmark won't work? I'm not familiar with perfkit but if a section for Azure credentials isn't included in the .boto file, maybe it's not needed.

Comment: I did that config and was able to run iperf benchmark. object_storage_service benchmark seems to require additional credentials, passed in.

Answer (score 0):

No additional configurations are required foro conducting storage test as we have to do for aws or google cloud. storage related benchmarking failes due to a bug. 
You might be getting errors asking you to retry test at some other region.

"--zones" tag defines location for virtual machines only and "--object_storage_region" is the additional argument you need to provide to select the datacenter where storage related benchmarking needs to be done.

Here is little more explanation by Google cloud platform member.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/PerfKitBenchmarker/issues/1111

I have successfully completed Azure Storage test with following arguments.

```
./pkb.py --cloud=Azure --benchmarks=object_storage_service -storage=Azure --zones="North Europe"  --object_storage_scenario=cli --object_storage_region="North Europe"
```